error: while connecting UE to ENODEB using adalm pluto with srsran 5g framework
in out project we are trying to run 5g srsran framework on adalm pluto .we are unable to attach ue to enodeb.we are running srsran in docker conatiner . below i have mention the terminal output.
we have connect one adalm pluto with srsran enodbe to create enodeb and other with srsran ue for ue
gnodeb terminal:
Soapy has found device #0: device=PlutoSDR, driver=plutosdr, label=PlutoSDR #0 usb:1.6.5, uri=usb:1.6.5, 
Selecting Soapy device: 0
[INFO] Opening label PlutoSDR #0 usb:1.6.5...
[INFO] Opening URI usb:1.6.5...
Setting up Rx stream with 1 channel(s)
[INFO] Using format CF32.
[INFO] USB direct mode enabled!
[INFO] RX timestamping enabled, every 1920 samples
[INFO] Has direct RX copy: 1
Setting up Tx stream with 1 channel(s)
[INFO] Using format CF32.
[INFO] TX timestamping enabled, every 1920 samples
[INFO] Has direct TX copy: 1
Available device sensors: 
 - xadc_temp0
 - xadc_voltage0
 - xadc_voltage1
 - xadc_voltage2
 - xadc_voltage3
 - xadc_voltage4
 - xadc_voltage5
 - xadc_voltage6
 - xadc_voltage7
 - xadc_voltage8
 - adm1177_current0
 - adm1177_voltage0
 - ad9361-phy_temp0
 - ad9361-phy_voltage2
Available sensors for Rx channel 0: 
State of gain elements for Rx channel 0 (AGC supported):
 - PGA: 40.00 dB
State of gain elements for Tx channel 0 (AGC not supported):
 - PGA: 80.00 dB
Rx antenna set to A_BALANCED
Tx antenna set to A

==== eNodeB started ===
Type <t> to view trace
Setting frequency: DL=2680.0 Mhz, UL=2560.0 MHz for cc_idx=0 nof_prb=50

ue terminal:
type hereSoapy has found device #0: device=PlutoSDR, driver=plutosdr, label=PlutoSDR #1 usb:1.7.5, uri=usb:1.7.5, 
Selecting Soapy device: 0
[INFO] Opening label PlutoSDR #1 usb:1.7.5...
[INFO] Opening URI usb:1.7.5...
Setting up Rx stream with 1 channel(s)
[INFO] Using format CF32.
[INFO] USB direct mode enabled!
[INFO] RX timestamping enabled, every 1920 samples
[INFO] Has direct RX copy: 1
Setting up Tx stream with 1 channel(s)
[INFO] Using format CF32.
[INFO] TX timestamping enabled, every 1920 samples
[INFO] Has direct TX copy: 1
Available device sensors: 
 - xadc_temp0
 - xadc_voltage0
 - xadc_voltage1
 - xadc_voltage2
 - xadc_voltage3
 - xadc_voltage4
 - xadc_voltage5
 - xadc_voltage6
 - xadc_voltage7
 - xadc_voltage8
 - adm1177_current0
 - adm1177_voltage0
 - ad9361-phy_temp0
 - ad9361-phy_voltage2
Available sensors for Rx channel 0: 
State of gain elements for Rx channel 0 (AGC supported):
 - PGA: 40.00 dB
State of gain elements for Tx channel 0 (AGC not supported):
 - PGA: 80.00 dB
Rx antenna set to A_BALANCED
Tx antenna set to A
Waiting PHY to initialize ... done!
Attaching UE...
.


